# Is it possible to rotate (alternate) table content between cells?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a `table` with 3 cells and I was wondering if I could "rotate" the data between each cell?

Basically, so after a set amount of time I want the data in the first cell to move to the second cell, the second cell data to move to the third cell and the third cell data to move to the first cell and so on...

I'm guessing if it's possible it would require some form of JavaScript?

**I'm open to all possible solutions**

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

[**MY TABLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5EUX/)

```
<table class="three" width="150" height="35%" border="1"><tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center" valign="bottom" style="font-size:30px;"><strong>T/O: £48k</strong></td></tr>
<tr>
<td width="60" align="center" style="font-size:12px"><strong>GP:£7k</strong>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center" style="font-size:12px"><strong>M:15%</strong>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if you want to do this on the client, you need javascript. As such it will involve playing with DOM, use jquery to make your life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use jQuery to do this as it requires manipulation of the DOM. In addition to this I would separate the styling from the markup.

```
// Store the TRs to a variable
var $tr = $('.three tr');

// Write a function
!function reDraw() {

    // Identify the TDs
    var $td1 = $tr.eq(0).find('td'),
        $td2 = $tr.eq(1).find('td').eq(0),
        $td3 = $tr.eq(1).find('td').eq(1);

    // Reshuffle TDs, and apply correct colspan
    $td2.insertBefore( $td1 ).attr('colspan','2');
    $td1.insertAfter( $td3 ).attr('colspan','1');

    // Refresh after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(reDraw, 2000);
}();
```

Check it out on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agrimsrud/Y5EUX/5/)

Comment: Happy to help :) Hope you make it work on your site!